# Import css variable from an external css file

Tags: css, css-variables

Im trying to use a variable defined in 'style.css' and import that file to 'theme.css'.
The issue is that the variable isnt accessible yet. No image appears on the background of discord.

style.css

```
:root {
    --customImg: "https://initiate.alphacoders.com/images/133/stretched-1920-1080-1330237.png?7641";
}
```

theme.css

```
@import './style.css';

:root {
   /* Background image variable */
   --background-image: var(--customImg);
 }
```

When I tried this, I was expecting to see the image in the background but nothing changed. There was no image.

Answer (score 0):

`@import` works, but you need to specify `url()` in the variable:

```css
/* style.css */

:root {
  --customImg: url("https://initiate.alphacoders.com/images/133/stretched-1920-1080-1330237.png?7641");
}
```

```css
/* theme.css */

@import 'style.css';

body {
  background-image: var(--customImg);
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't change anything. Theres no image. In the theme.css it must be :root

Comment: https://initiate.alphacoders.com/images/133/stretched-1920-1080-1330237.png?7641 - **404**. Maybe that's why?

Comment: i tried with this now https://i.imgur.com/l7Bg8HJ.png
nothing changed as well

Comment: if i do this the image appears

@import './styles.css';
/* theme.css */
:root{
  /* Background image variables */
  --background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/l7Bg8HJ.png");
}

Comment: Dude, special took your time to prove it works. Here is the links:

https://imhvost.github.io/77293123.html

https://imhvost.github.io/77293123-theme.css 
https://imhvost.github.io/77293123-style.css

Comment: ive tried it as well, here try with the source code of the theme

https://github.com/almofada1/customImg

Comment: And then, how do you apply it? I've provided you with a reproducible example that proves it works. So give me a reproducible example where it doesn't work or the conversation is over.

Comment: its a discord theme, using better discord you put the theme in the themes folder